# Посмотреть, что делает процесс PHP

Tags: php, linux

Есть несколько PHP-cgi процессов, как посмотреть что они делают (хотя бы один) в данный момент? Например, какой файл выполняет. Или GET-запрос. Нужно, чтобы оценить, какие модули системы выполняются.

С инструментами `Xdebug` и `XHprof` знаком, но есть ли альтернатива? Какой-нибудь Linux-путь типа посмотреть какие файлы открыты.

Что сделано:

Получил PID процессов

```
ps aux | grep php
```

Получил рабочий каталог - на сервере несколько виртуалхостов, уже что-то

```
ls -ld /proc/16945/cwd
```

Comment: файлы не обязательно могут быть и открыты. если используется кэш опкодов/или файлов, то он просто в памяти будет висеть и оттуда выполнятся

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут два момента.

1) Чтобы узнать код какого именно php-скрипта исполняется в данный момент(include) - необходим доступ к массиву исполняющихся опкодов, а это внутренняя логика PHP и каких либо универсальных linux-инструментов тут придумать сложно

2) Жизнь скрипта, в общем случае, очень коротка (а отработка массива опкодов для конкретной функции, например, и того меньше). С какой бы частотой вы не опрашивали текущее состояние - это будет оооочень дырявая статистика.

Так что подход типа "наблюдатель" тут слабо применим и гораздо больше подходит подход "слушатель", когда ваш сборщик статистики будет оповещаться о необходимых событиях самим PHP. А это как раз те самые Xdebug, XHprof и т.д.